# When moving cells in UITableView, how do I make a cell remain stationary?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a list of people that occupy spots. I want the user to be able to rearrange these people into different spots, however, some spots are off limits. I thought this would be most easily accomplished using UITableView's rearrangement capabilities. However, I can't figure out how to keep my unavailable spots stationary.

For example, I want to move Activia Boulanger to spot 5. The grey cells should be the immoveable cells.

The beginning view:

[image: Beginning]

What the UITableView does automatically:

[image: What UITableView does]

What I want UITableView to do:

[image: What I want]

Setting `tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath:` seems to just prevent you from being able to move a cell, but does not prevent the cell from moving in reaction to other cells' movements.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

---

UPDATE:
Below is some sample code with a setup for the problem. I have not included my efforts at a solution because they have all failed and would clutter things up.

```
#import "LDYViewController.h"

static NSString * unmoveableCellId = @"NoMove";
static NSString * moveableCellId = @"OkMove";

@implementation LDYViewController
@synthesize tableView;
@synthesize peopleList;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    peopleList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                  @"Belinda Boomer", @"Activia Boulanger", @"Arnold Carter", [NSNull null], @"Attila Creighton", [NSNull null], @"Bruce Cleary", [NSNull null], nil];
    [tableView setEditing:YES];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return peopleList.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if([peopleList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] == [NSNull null]) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:unmoveableCellId];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:unmoveableCellId];
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        }
    } else {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:moveableCellId];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:moveableCellId];
            NSString * name = [peopleList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = name;
        }        
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath {
}

- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath
       toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath {
    return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([peopleList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] == [NSNull null]) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}    
@end
```

Comment: how do you represent the blanks in your people array?  in the datasource array that supports this table.

Comment: They are null entries: [NSNull null]. When I come across a null entry, I create an "unmoveable" cell type.

Comment: After the move, can you just reorder your array to move the nulls back to positions 3, 5, 7 etc?

Comment: Do you mean the underlying array? I just double checked and it looks like the developer is responsible for reordering the underlying array to respond to a rearrangement in the UI. I have also tried doing a `tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` in both `tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:      toProposedIndexPath:` and `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:`, and there seem to be weird state issues occurring when I do this.

Comment: Yes, it's the app's job.  I think you can get the desired effect just by constraining how the people array is altered on the move.  No need for any additional tableView calls.  Can you post your move code as it is?

Comment: @danh, I have just posted some code. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the normal rearrange logic on your model, then when it's done, put the nulls back in where you want them.  Posted code doesn't include the model, so here's a plausible model to illustrate:

```
// always leave our array with a null at indexes 3,5,7
// i'm sure you have better logic about where nulls go, but just to illustrate
- (void)addNulls {

    NSMutableArray *answer = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (id object in self.peopleList) {
        if (![object isKindOfClass:[NSNull self]]) {
            [answer addObject:object];
        }
    }

    assert(answer.count >= 4);
    [answer insertObject:[NSNull null] atIndex:3];
    [answer insertObject:[NSNull null] atIndex:5];
    [answer insertObject:[NSNull null] atIndex:7];
    self.peopleList = answer;
}

// build a pretend model with nulls
- (NSMutableArray *)peopleList {

    if (!_peopleList) {
        _peopleList = [NSMutableArray array];
        [_peopleList addObject:@"Moe"];
        [_peopleList addObject:@"Larry"];
        [_peopleList addObject:@"Curly"];
        [_peopleList addObject:[NSNull null]];
        [_peopleList addObject:@"Groucho"];
        [_peopleList addObject:[NSNull null]];
        [_peopleList addObject:@"Chico"];
        [_peopleList addObject:[NSNull null]];
        [_peopleList addObject:@"Harpo"];
    }
    return _peopleList;
}



// normal rearrange logic, then fix your array up
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {

    // reorder the list with the typical logic, ignoring nulls
    NSString *stringToMove = [self.peopleList objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [self.peopleList removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [self.peopleList insertObject:stringToMove atIndex:toIndexPath.row];

    // now put nulls into the positions you want them
    [self addNulls];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: For some reason the reload data seems to put everything back where it was originally rather than where the model specifies. I've double checked the resulting model, and that's ok. Does yours behave differently? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I checked this code in my own table vc and it worked correctly.  The model not changing is evidence that the moveRowAtIndexPath is not working or getting called.  Try putting a breakpoint in there and examine the model before and after.

Comment: I figured out what my issue was. It was very dumb: when I was redrawing the cells, I nested my name assignments under testing a null cell, so because the cell in row x already existed, it didn't rewrite the names. Thanks for your patience! Now if only I could make it so the grey bars don't slide up during the animation. Any ideas for that? :)

Comment: I thought about that while prototyping, and (1) I couldn't think of a way to do it besides replacing all that great, free, apple animation with less skillful DIY, and (2) would we really want it?  If the blank rows remained fixed, how would user visualize where the insert will happen relative to the user non-null rows?  The default behavior isn't perfect, but i think if you try to visualize -in detail- what should be done instead, you might discover the alternatives are equally imperfect and much more difficult to implement.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)sourceIndexPath
       toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
```

You can check the proposedDestinationIndexPath, if you don't want to move row to it, you can return the sourceIndexPath then row will be moved back, otherwise return the proposedDestinationIndexPath.

Comment: In the example I gave above, index 5 is an allowable location for the cell, however, my grey cells still move. This issue isn't so much that I can move a cell to where my grey cell is, it's that the grey cells move in reaction to the other cells' movements. I've tried something similar to this: If I try to move a cell to where a grey cell is, I increases the row so that I'm forced to move the cell one lower. This prevents me from moving cells to index 4 (where the grey cell is), but the grey cell still moves up along with all the other cells, and I still end up with image 2.

Comment: Then I think all suggestions here in this thread won't help you, you should do try way something like:
- Split spots into 3 groups (morning, afternoon, evening), each group will be a section in your table.
- Each group will have a fixed number of spots, then when you move an item from a section to another, firstly, check to shift up an item to take place of moved item. :)

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar problem and solved it.

create 2 section and put all gray color rows in section 2.

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath{

if (proposedDestinationIndexPath.section == 1)
    return sourceIndexPath;
else
    return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
```

}

Comment: Wouldn't this group all of my grey cells together?

Comment: Worked perfectly for me! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath{
```

In this method you need to check the from indexIndexPath and toIndexPath to check if the user is moving to an invalid position.  The modify the tableview's datasource to either put the cell back or move it to the correct position.

Comment: I gave this a try. If I attempted to move Activia to position 4, I changed the toIndexPath to position 5. However, this just ended up moving cells 4 and 5 as if they were one block, which resulted in the same positions as image 2.

Comment: Actually, I think I may have misunderstood your response. I will give this a try.

Comment: I tried modifying the datasource to match the view I would like. Even after reloading the table, this doesn't seem to help. I looked up `[UITableView reloadData]` and it says that "it should not be called in the methods that insert or delete rows". Maybe that's why the reload didn't work? I have just added some code to the question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift Implementation**

```
class TableViewMovable: UITableView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var arrDataSource = [[String:Int]]()

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    commonInit()
}

func commonInit(){

    dataSource = self
    delegate = self
    isEditing = true

    register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrDataSource.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") {
        cell.textLabel?.text = arrDataSource[indexPath.row].keys.first!
        let val = arrDataSource[indexPath.row].values.first!
        cell.backgroundColor = val % 2 == 0 ? UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.5) : UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        return cell
    }else{
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return .none
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let movedObject = arrDataSource[sourceIndexPath.row]
    arrDataSource.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    arrDataSource.insert(movedObject, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
    debugPrint("\(sourceIndexPath.row) => \(destinationIndexPath.row)")

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

}

Hope this might help someone.